# Mailing result of shell script in .xls file in unix

Tags: excel, bash, unix

I am trying to send output of shell script to my email, i am getting plain text on my email but i want to colour the cell of my excel sheet based on the cell value. please let me know the feasibility. Do i need to use some other language for the purpose?

Below is the code:

#!/bin/bash
sep='\t'

(For editing file)
echo -ne "Stage${sep}Refresh Type${sep}LB - Start_Date${sep}R - Start_Date${sep}R - End_Date${sep}Check Description${sep}Flag${sep}Status${sep}" >/home/mshilton/QA_E2E_Automation/qa_results/Refresh_results.csv
echo "                                          " >>/home/mshilton/QA_E2E_Automation/qa_results/Refresh_results.csv
hive -e "select * from hilton_qa.QA_Refresh_Final_Status_1;" >>/home/mshilton/QA_E2E_Automation/qa_results/Refresh_results.csv

( For exporting mail)
export MAIL_LIST="m****il@marketshare.com"
echo  "Pls find the attachment for Refresh_Type refresh All Stages validation results"|mail -r "Hilton_QA@360D" -s "Refresh_Type Weekly Refresh QA All Stages Status" -a /home/mshilton/QA_E2E_Automation/qa_results/Refresh_results.csv < /home/mshilton/QA_E2E_Automation/qa_results/Refresh_results.csv   $MAIL_LIST

Answer (score 0):

I know of know way to store formatting information in a CSV file and have Excel automatically use that to colour a cell.  I suspect it is very unlikely you will be able to.  CSV is meant to be a plain-text format.

You do have a couple of options:

1. Create a proper Excel file directly, including formatting information (a .xlsx file is human readable / writable after unzipping, if you can wade your way through the hideous documentation; Python has [modules](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/) which might make it easier than doing it directly).
2. Embed a formatting code and have Excel run a macro (e.g. in Visual Basic for Applications) when you import the file, to recognise the code, remove it, and colour the cell.

Sorry I couldn't give a more optimistic answer.

Comment: Can you please help me in getting output of the query mentioned in the above program (ie "hive -e "select * from hilton_qa.QA_Refresh_Final_Status_1;"  should be generating HTML file, please note currently i am getting a flat text file.